# opencv optical flow does not detect most of the vectors

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

I'm using optical flow on a traffic video which are relatively small (288 x 360) and I have a problem. I can't get the optical flow vectors of some places in the frame.
This image shows the points that were detected as "good features to track" by the

> goodFeaturesToTrack()

function like this:

```
vector<Point2f>  features1;
vector<Point2f>  features2;
int number_of_features = 2000;
goodFeaturesToTrack(frame1, features1 ,number_of_features,0.01,0.01);
```

[image]

and you see a lot of points were detected in the back but when I use

> calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()

to get the optical flow vectors like this:

```
TermCriteria optical_flow_termination_criteria= TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10, .001 );

calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(
frame1, frame2, features1, features2,
optical_flow_found_feature,optical_flow_feature_error,
Size(21,21),5,optical_flow_termination_criteria
);
```

it only returns points in the front as in the image blow:

[image]

But I need vectors of all the video. So how can I get vectors from the back as well?

Edit:

What I was doing wrong was that I was filtering small vectors.

Comment: Can you show the step between `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` and drawing the vectors?

Comment: Thank you! the problem was a one line filter right there and I was fixated that there was something wrong with my use of the function. If you add the answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are doing some kind of processing/filtering of the optical flow vectors before displaying them.